# Find maximum and minimum values for n digits in base d

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Even if I know that with `n` digits the minimum value in base `d` is $d^{n-1}$ and the maximum is $d^{n}-1$, I would like to know how to add a simple justification for this.

For example, for 4 digits in base 7, the minimum is $(1000) _{7}$, which is $7^3$ and maximum is $6666 _{7}$ which is $7^4 - 1$

Comment: You might want to use $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (d-1) d^{i-1} = d^n-1$ and $d^{n-1}\le d^n-1 \lt d^n$

Comment: @Henry could you make an answer with more steps? I've never used summation before so I don't know it's properties, but I see it is the key for the exercise. Thank you!

Comment: It is difficult to know what you are allowed to assume, but essentially it is the same as proving any natural number can be written uniquely in base ten and any $n$ digit base ten number must be bigger than an $n-1$ digit base ten number.  Then change ten to $7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number in $n$ digits in base $d$ is a number of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kd^k$$
where $0 \leq a_k \leq {d-1}$ for all $k$ and $a_{n-1} \geq 1$.

From $a_k \leq {d-1}$, we can conclude that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kd^k \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(d-1)d^k = d^n-1.$$

This proves that the maximum is indeed $d^n - 1$ (reached when $a_k = d-1$ for all $k$).

From $a_{n-1} \geq 1$ and $a_k \geq 0$, we get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kd^k \geq d^{n-1},$$
which proves that the minimum is indeed $d^{n-1}$ (reached when $a_{n-1} = 1$ and $a_k = 0$ for $k < n-1$).